# Converting laravelcollective/html form to plain HTML

Tags: laravel

I know that this should be simple, but I'm new to Laravel and have never used the Collective tag. I'm struggling to convert the below to plain vanilla HTML format for editing.

```
{!! Form::select('roles[]', $roles,[], array('class' => 'select2 form-select')) !!}
```

Here is what I have tried to get all the already selected checkboxes for editing in my Laravel Blade, and I expected to get the selected boxes from the database and edit them.

`<select class="form-select" name="role[]"> @foreach ($roles as $role) <option value="$roles[]">{{ $role->name }}</option> @endforeach </select>`

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the selected attribute to mark the option as selected if it matches the value you want to select...

```
<select class="form-select" name="roles[]">
    @foreach ($roles as $role)
        <option value="{{ $role->id }}" {{ in_array($role->id, $selectedRoles) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            {{ $role->name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Karl for the help. I'm getting this error: Attempt to read property "id" on string.

Comment: Thanks Karl, got it sorted by adapting your code